# Неожиданный результат

Tags: c

форумчане! Выполнял ДЗ по основам программирования(1 курс) и столкнулся с проблемой. Программа работала корректно до момента рефакторинга, потом начала выбивать очень странные результаты. Все перепроверил сотню раз и не нашел в чем проблема.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    printf("\n------------------------------------ПРЕДУПРЕЖДЕНИЕ-----------------------------------\n");
    printf("Минимальное число по умолчанию: 0\nМаксимальное число по умолчанию: 1");
    printf("\n------------------------------------ПРЕДУПРЕЖДЕНИЕ-----------------------------------\n");

    double array[5], a, min = 0, max = 1;
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("\nВведите число №%i: \n", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &a);

        array[i] = a;

        if (array[i] > max) {
            max = array[i];
        };
        if (array[i] < min) {
            min = array[i];
        };
    };
    

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (array[i] > min && array[i] < max) {
            count++;
        };
    };

    printf("\n------------------------------------ОТЧЁТ ПО РАБОТЕ-----------------------------------\n");
    printf("Найбольшее число: %d\n Найменьшее число: %d \n Количество элементов между ними: %i", max, min, count);
    printf("\n------------------------------------ОТЧЁТ ПО РАБОТЕ-----------------------------------\n");
}
```

Comment: scanf("%d", &a); а вы тут уверены?) При выводе кстати тоже.

Comment: Я не до конца разобрался с типизацией(я JS девелопер, не хочу переходить на С, поэтому мотивации учить не особо). Дабл может вызывать проблемы?

Comment: не совсем. вам нужно открыть документацию по спецификатором вывода. %d это целое число если что.

Comment: Да и логика с `min = 0, max = 1` непонятна. А что по условию задачи нужно сделать?

Comment: https://cpp.com.ru/shildt_spr_po_c/08/0804.html вот например. Дробные числа кстати на равенство вот так проверять не всегда дорогая идея.

Comment: Условие задачи: Подсчитать количество элементов одномерного числового массива, расположенных между наибольшим и наименьшим значениями элементов массива

Comment: кхм... тогда цикл не нужен. как ни странно, но это abs(max - min) - 1.

Comment: Так нам нужно количество элементов между максимумом и минимумом.

Comment: я имел в виду позиции. между наверное имеется в виду в массиве между 2 элементами а не просто весь массив минус максимум и минимум. для дробных чисел в противном случае ответ N - 2 будет почти всегда (3).

Comment: Хм, могли бы тогда сделать правку? Я не сильно понял как правильно реализовать. Препод душный(хочет чтобы ей за сессию заплатили), так что она предьявит за мельчайшую ошибку

Comment: "*Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.*" Где у вас желаемое поведение, и явное описание проблемы? Ни что программа должна делать, ни в чем проявляется ее наработоспособность...

Comment: Справедливо. Но я нашел ошибку

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была с изначальной инициализацией и проверкой min, max. Фактически минимальное число больше 0 уже ломало код. Помог перенос логики проверки в отдельный цикл и значения min, max задаются первым числом массива, поэтому и инициализация не понадобилась.